# Pass test number from robotframework to python

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a robot test table and am running pybot. The robot/pybot calls a python function. Can I pass the test number to my python function ?

I realize I can do this by appending a number to my robot test table, but its painful to do this because its a huge table with formatting. Is there another way?

The tests are like (shorter form of the actual test table, its too big to paste)

```
=================================================
Test Case           Action          Arguments
=================================================
Test connection   mytest.setup      ${Bucket}
Verify files      mytest.verify     ${filename}
Search logs       mytest.searchlog  ${string_to_search}
==================================================
```

So when I call mytest.searchlog() in python (mytest is my python file), how do I tell it that this is the 3rd test case?

I am running it with pybot

```
pybot --variable Bucket:mybucket .....  testfile.rst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can implement this using a counter that is reset every test case and stores it's value in the Test Case variable scope.

Using the data driven example found [here](https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/robotdemo) I created the below example where the test case has the `[setup]` section added and the keyword that is called each time for every data record has a `[teardown]` section. Although it could handled inside the keyword as well.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Calculation error     [Template]    Calculation should fail
                      [setup]    Set Test Variable     ${counter}    0
                      kekkonen      Invalid button 'k'.
                      ${EMPTY}      Invalid expression.
                      1 / 0         Division by zero.
*** Keywords ***
Calculation should fail
    [Arguments]    ${expression}    ${expected}
    ${error} =    Should cause error    C${expression}=
    Should be equal    ${expected}    ${error}    # Using `BuiltIn` keyword
    [teardown]    Counter

Counter
    ${countr}=       Get Variable Value   ${counter}
    ${countr}=     evaluate    ${countr}+1
    Set Test Variable    ${counter}    ${countr}
```

The variable can be called within the scope of the Test Case, this also includes the keywords that are called within that given test case.